# Dynamic REST Statements

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api, custom-javascript

Is there a way to dynamically create a REST call and specifically I am referring to the data: section of the call.  If I get the terminology incorrect by all means keep me honest.  I tried some things with no success.  I looked at the __metadata portion and thought this was a key/value pair and tried some substitution with no luck. Same for the field:value pairs.  Been poking around on stack to try to find something with no luck so far.

So, in the following REST example is there a way to "break out" the information following the __metadata in the brackets and also the field:value immediately after the brackets.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: odataUrl, 
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    processData: false,
    headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            //"If-Match": "*", 
            //"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
    },
              
    data: JSON.stringify(
        {
        __metadata :{
            **"type":"SP.Data.ErrorHandlerListItem"
        },
        Title:"TEST",
        ver:'2.0',
        modname:'no name'**
        

    }),
```

I tried using the following with no luck as an example setting the variables outside the REST statement and replacing the metadata statement with the following vars.

```
var typetest={"type":"SP."+TargetListName+"ListItem"};
var savetst={Title:"projname",ver:'test',modname:'browsertest'};
     data: JSON.stringify(
         {
          __metadata :{typetest},savetxt
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting pretty close.  Yes, you definitely can use variables to make certain parts of the data that you send to SharePoint dynamic.

First. let me point out a couple errors I see in the way you have structured your first attempt there:

```
var typetest={"type":"SP."+TargetListName+"ListItem"};
var savetst={Title:"projname",ver:'test',modname:'browsertest'};

// i am assuming the above lines are not actually inside the
// ajax call, and you were just showing appreviated code

     data: JSON.stringify({
          __metadata :{typetest},savetxt
         })
```

If we break down what you have inside the `JSON.stringify()` function, and "fill in" what you have defined in the variables, you get

```
JSON.stringify({
    __metadata: {
            { "type": "SP."+TargetListName+"ListItem" } // notice you end up with double curly braces here
        },
        {                       // and you end up with curly braces here, after the comma after "__metadata", instead of just straight key/value pairs
            Title:"projname",
            ver:'test',
            modname:'browsertest'
        }
})
```

Also, in the first example, for the metadata type you have

```
"SP.Data.ErrorHandlerListItem"
```

while in your "dynamic" version you have

```
"SP."+TargetListName+"ListItem"
```

which would really end up as `"SP.ErrorHandlerListItem"`, which is missing that `.Data.` part, so you really want

```
"SP.Data." + TargetListName + "ListItem"
```

That all being said, the way I would make this easier to work with is to not put the data payload object inline with the `JSON.stringify()` function, but to make it it's own separate object in a variable, like this

```
var payload = {
    __metadata :{
        "type":"SP.Data.ErrorHandlerListItem"
    },
    Title:"TEST",
    ver:'2.0',
    modname:'no name'
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: odataUrl, 
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    processData: false,
    headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            //"If-Match": "*", 
            //"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(payload)
});
```

Then you can start to do things like

```
function getMetadataTypeValue (listName) {
    // you can do more sophisticated stuff in here
    // like deal with spaces in the list name
    return "SP.Data." + listName + "ListItem";
}

var titleValue = "TEST";  // or some other way of dynamically generating this
var versionValue = "2.0"; // or dynamically determined
var modValue = "no name"; // etc

var payload = {
    __metadata: {
        "type": getMetadataTypeValue(dynamicTargetListName)
    },
    Title: titleValue,
    ver: versionValue,
    modname: modValue
}
```

Also, JavaScript is very forgiving, and you can add properties to an object dynamically just by *defining* it using dot notation on the fly. So you can start with:

```
var payload = {
    __metadata: {
        "type": "SP.Data." + listName + "ListItem" // assume listName = "ErrorHandler"
    }
}
```

Now your original `payload` object is *only*

```
{  __metadata: {
     "type": "SP.Data.ErrorHandlerListItem"
   }
}
```

but then you can do something like

```
var needToAddTitle = true;
var titleValue = "Updated Title";

if (needToAddTitle) {
    payload.Title = titleValue;
}
```

*Now* your `payload` object is

```
{  __metadata: {
     "type": "SP.Data.ErrorHandlerListItem"
   },
   Title: "Updated Title"
}
```

*but* if `needToAddTitle = false` and the line `payload.Title = titleValue` is never executed, then the `payload` object is still

```
{  __metadata: {
     "type": "SP.Data.ErrorHandlerListItem"
   }
}
```

because you never defined `payload.Title = something`.

In that way you can dynamically build up each of the properties you need on the `payload` object, and not only dynamically add each property as needed, but use variables to set the property values, or even call functions to dynamically generate (and `return`) the property values.

Then, once your `payload` is set up the way you want, then you do your `ajax` call, passing the `payload` variable/object into the `JSON.stringify()` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: odataUrl, 
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    processData: false,
    headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Content-Type":"application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest":$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            //"If-Match": "*", 
            //"X-HTTP-Method": "MERGE"
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(payload)
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  Made my life much easier.

Comment: Now that I have had a chance to play with this it's on target with where I wanted to go perfectly.  In the SP.Data.listnameListItem metadata property I tried using the listname but it seems it wants the ListItemEntityFullName value which is what I wanted to do anyhow.  Yeah!